# "Call this number from your phone" feature can't find connected phone in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, android

I have Chrome installed on both my PC and Android 11 Phone (Oneplus 8T). But when I click on a phone number on my PC, it just asks me to sign in to Chrome on my phone.

But I am already signed into Chrome on my phone. Is there a setting that is preventing this feature from working?

What should a do?

Comment: Are you signed into Chrome on the phone but not on the PC?

Comment: @harrymc I am signed into both with same account

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the sign-in message & dialog?

Comment: @harrymc https://imgur.com/a/fSViOYZ Here are 4 screenshots. I use GSuite. But it used to work with GSuite earlier so I doubt it's the issue.

Comment: he message seems to imply 3 Chrome windows that are signed into 3 different profiles. Is that correct?

Comment: @harrymc Only the first profile is logged into sync. The remaining 2 are not, and the last one is guest.

Comment: Does this message still arrive when the other two profiles are closed?

Comment: @harrymc No. They are always closed 95% of time.

Comment: No it doesn't arrive when they are closed, or it arrives also when they are closed?

Comment: @harrymc Regardless of open/close status of other 2 profiles, call from mobile link in main profile doesn't works.